# Sort for 3 values

Tags: javascript, sorting

So I have an array of objects and I have 2 boolean values I need to sort in priority of corporate_sponsor and title then visitor_bureau and title then the rest by title.

```
let array = [{
    "title": "A Some Place",
    "visitor_bureau": "0",
    "corporate_sponsor" : "0"
  }, {
    "title": "B Some Place",
    "visitor_bureau": "1",
    "corporate_sponsor": "1"
  }, {
    "title": "C Some Place",
    "visitor_bureau": "1",
    "corporate_sponsor" : "1"
}];
```

The code I am using right now is only set to sort the visitor_bureau and title but I need to add another element to it.

```
var sorted = array.sort((a, b) => b.visitor_bureau - a.visitor_bureau || a.title.localeCompare(b.title));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So add it, you already have a template to follow.

Comment: Wow thanks for the minus. Trying to learn something new and I get a minus. Some of this might not come as easy to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can imagine yourself having to add more properties in the future, it would make more sense to create an abstraction to sort by whatever properties you need than to augment your method each time (making it more complex and less readable).

I have defined a function `sorterBy` which you can pass a sequence of arrays representing each property you want to sort by, in priority order. It returns a function that can be used as an argument to `Array#sort`. Using it looks like this (where "sort order" is `1` for ascending and `-1` for descending):

```
let sorted = [...array].sort(sorterBy(
//[<name>, <type>, <sort order>]
  ['corporate_sponsor', 'number', -1],
  ['visitor_bureau', 'number', -1],
  ['title', 'string', 1]
))
```

```js
function sorterBy (...properties) {
  return (a, b) => {
    let result = 0
    for (let property of properties) {
      if (result) return result
      else result = compare(a, b, property)
    }
    return result
  }
}

function compare(a, b, property) {
  let [name, type, direction = 1] = property
  a = a[name]
  b = b[name]
  if (direction === -1) [b, a] = [a, b]
  switch (type) {
    case 'number':
      a = +a
      b = +b
      return a < b ? -1 : a === b ? 0 : 1;
    case 'string':
      a += ''
      b += ''
      return a.localeCompare(b)
  }
  return 0
}


let array = [{
    "title": "A Some Place",
    "visitor_bureau": "0",
    "corporate_sponsor" : "0"
  }, {
    "title": "B Some Place",
    "visitor_bureau": "1",
    "corporate_sponsor": "1"
  }, {
    "title": "C Some Place",
    "visitor_bureau": "1",
    "corporate_sponsor" : "1"
}]

let sorted = [...array].sort(sorterBy(
  ['corporate_sponsor', 'number', -1],
  ['visitor_bureau', 'number', -1],
  ['title', 'string', 1]
))

console.log(array)
console.log(sorted)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out on my own.

```
var sorted = posts.sort((a, b) => b.corporate_sponsor - a.corporate_sponsor || b.visitor_bureau - a.visitor_bureau || a.title.localeCompare(b.title));
```